Instantiate lazy val which depends on runtime parameter in concurrent env
I need to instantiate MyHttpClient as Singleton. MyHttpClient is used by multiple threads.
Solution below works, but it's ugly and should have issue with endpoint, I just didn't hit it yet.
endpoint passed as runtime parameter, I don't know it in advance. It's apache spark, so I can't use easily stuff like guice. client is used inside map stages.
object MyHttpClientSingleton {
  var endpoint: Option[String] = None
  private lazy val client = new MyHttpClient(endpoint.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("endpoint is not set")))

  def getMyHttpClient(): MyHttpClient = {
    client
  }
}

// usage in code
val client = {
  MyHttpClientSingleton.endpoint = Some(endpoint)
  MyHttpClientSingleton.getMyHttpClient()
}
client.doStuff()


endpoint is known at a point of time when spark job is started.
endpoint should be passed in runtime, client accepts endpoint and can connect to various environments.


Show us more context. When is endpoint known? Why is your client dependant on the endpoint, I'd expect to use the same client instance no matter the endpoint.

Why not just instantiate the client in the main, pass it down to all the things that need it on their constructors, and forget about enforcing something as silly as a singleton.

There isn't a singleton for all of spark model, the closest is broadcast variables, but the state should be immutable to be predictable.
Your best bet is to distribute the configuration information through a broadcast variable which uses a transient lazy val to initialise connections etc. (one initialisation per executor - not per partition), so similar to what you currently have but not a typical singleton local to a single jvm.
This works fine as long as you don't need to close resources (e.g. you can leave it to garbage collection).  If you actually need to control the connections in a more fine grained fashion you may need to look at plugins that allows executor plugin instances to know when they have finished a task (or message/rpc the driver).
